# Memoized vs non-memoized time complexity analysis for combination sums

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand why using `lru_cache` to solve this problem yields a slower performance of the code.

[The question](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/description/) is essentially to return all combinations that add up to a certain target.

I'm using the `lru_cache` decorator to do the memoization ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)), and this is my solution:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def combinationSum(candidates, target):
    return dfs(tuple(candidates), 0, target)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def dfs(candidates, i, target):
    if target < 0:
        return []

    if target == 0:
        return [[]]

    if i == len(candidates):
        return []

    final_results = []
    for j in range(i, len(candidates)):

        results = dfs(candidates, j, target - candidates[j])

        for x in results:
            final_results.append([candidates[j]] + x)

    return final_results
```

It seems like when the `lru_cache` decorator is commented out, I get almost a 50% increase in the runtime speed of this algorithm. This seems a little counter intuitive as I thought the time complexity of the solution should be reduced, even with the increased overhead of function calls to retrieve results from the memoization.

For the memoized solution, I believe the time complexity should be `O(n^2*k*2^n)` where `n` is the length of the array, and `k` being all numbers in the range from `0` to `target`.

This is my analysis (need a little help verifying):

```
time complexity 
= possible states for memoization x work done at each step
= (n * k) * (n * maximum size of results)
= n * k * n * 2^n
```

I'm also missing some gaps in my knowledge on how to analyze the time complexity of the recursive solution, I could use some help in doing so!

EDIT:

I'm using `range(1, 10000)` as a test input, here are the benchmarks:

```
# with lru_cache
$ time python3 combination_sum.py
CacheInfo(hits=59984, misses=49996, maxsize=None, currsize=49996)

real    0m4.031s
user    0m3.996s
sys     0m0.024s

# without lru_cache
$ time python3 combination_sum.py

real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Comment: Please give the specific arguments you're using.  Whether a cache helps or hurts depends a whole lot on the cache hit rate, and it's impossible to _guess_ which hit rate you're getting without knowing the arguments you're using.

Comment: what type `candidates` is?

Comment: Lower complexity does not guarantee lower time.  It just means it grows more slowly at large values.  For small values it is perfectly valid that it takes longer.

Comment: @skyboyer candidates is a list of integers

Comment: @TimPeters I've updated the question with the input I'm using!

Comment: Is my analysis of the time complexity for the memoized solution correct? How do I go about analyzing the time complexity of the non-memoized solution?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give *both* arguments, and they're both important.  I can make either version much faster than the other by picking *specific* pairs.  If you're passing `range(1, 10000)` as `candidates`, then each cache lookup has to (among other things) do 9999 comparisons just to determine that the candidates are always the same - and that's huge overhead.  Try, e.g.,

```
combinationSum(range(1, 1000), 45) # not ten thousand, just one thousand
```

for a case where the cached version is much faster.  After which:

```
>>> dfs.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=930864, misses=44956, maxsize=None, currsize=44956)
```

"Analysis" is futile if you don't account for the expense of doing a cache lookup, and you're apparently *trying* cases where cache lookup is extremely expensive.  Dict lookup is expected-case `O(1)`, but the hidden constant factor can be arbitrarily large depending on how expensive equality-testing is (and for a key involving an `N`-element tuple, establishing equality requires at least `N` comparisons).

Which should suggest a major improvement:  keep `candidates` out of the argument list.  It's invariant so there's really no need to pass it.  Then the cache just needs to store fast-to-compare `(i, target)` pairs.

### EDIT: PRACTICAL CHANGES

Here's another version of the code that doesn't pass in `candidates`.  For

```
combinationSum(range(1, 10000), 45)
```

it's faster by at least a factor of 50 on my box.  There's one other material change:  don't do a recursive call when `target` is reduced below zero.  An enormous number of cache entries were recording empty-list results for `(j, negative_integer)` arguments.  This change reduced the final cache size from 449956 to 1036 in the case above - and cut the number of hits from 9444864 to 6853.

```
def combinationSum(candidates, target):

    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def dfs(i, target):
        if target == 0:
            return [[]]
        assert target > 0
        if i == n:
            return []
        final_results = []
        for j in range(i, n):
            cand = candidates[j]
            if cand <= target:
                results = dfs(j, target - cand)
                for x in results:
                    final_results.append([cand] + x)
        return final_results

    n = len(candidates)
    result = dfs(0, target)
    print(dfs.cache_info())
    return result
```

Comment: I'm such a fool, I completely overlooked the time complexity of the comparison of `candidates` throughout problems I worked through ><. Yeah, it seems like when I was passing in small values like `5` for `target`, it's easy for the recursion tree to be pruned as well, but when larger values are passed in, the effect of memoization becomes more apparent.

Comment: Now I have more intuition on why the memoized solution is faster for a larger input space, how can I analyze the time complexity of the plain recursive solution to compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following on your result

```
>>>dfs.cache_info()
```

you should get a result of something like this

```
CacheInfo(hits=2, misses=216, maxsize=None, currsize=216)
```

because your function parameters are very long so they don't match often with the cached values, I blame the target parameter here, restructuring the program might improve the hits drastically.

Comment: I've updated the question with the cache info results! Yes, probably restructuring will work, but I want to figure out the impact of using memoization on the solution – and why does the runtime slow down with memoization